# Installing PHP extension mbstring in PHP 5.6 CentOS 6.8

Tags: linux, centos, php, php.ini, php-extensions

I am using PHP 5.6 on my centos-release-6-8.el6.centos.12.3.x86_64 server.

I got following error from one of my PHP function.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding()
```

So, I tried to install mbstring extension. when I execute

```
sudo yum install php-mbstring
```

CLI returns

```
Package php-mbstring-5.6.25-1.el6.remi.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

And I aslo tried  "sudo yum install php56-mbstring"
This returns

```
No package php56-mbstring available. Nothing to do
```

But still, PHP function giving me that error and there is no 'mbsting' in phpinfo()

I also add the following line to httpd.conf

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
```

Server Restarted

Update:

```
[~]# php -v
PHP 5.6.22 (cli) (built: Jun 13 2016 11:43:51) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
[~]# php -m | grep mbstring
[~]# php -i | grep mbstring
```

Nothing returns to php -m | grep mbstring & php -i | grep mbstring

```
[~]# rpm -qil php-mbstring
Name        : php-mbstring                 Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 5.6.25                            Vendor: Remi Collet
Release     : 1.el6.remi                    Build Date: Wed 31 Aug 2016 18:33:05 BST
Install Date: Mon 05 Sep 2016 16:26:05 BST      Build Host: builder.remirepo.net
Group       : Development/Languages         Source RPM: php-5.6.25-1.el6.remi.src.rpm
Size        : 2856446                          License: PHP and LGPLv2 and BSD and OpenLDAP
Packager    : http://blog.remirepo.net/
URL         : http://www.php.net/
/etc/php-zts.d/20-mbstring.ini
/etc/php.d/20-mbstring.ini
/usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/mbstring.so
/usr/lib64/php/modules/mbstring.so
/usr/share/doc/php-mbstring-5.6.25
/usr/share/doc/php-mbstring-5.6.25/libmbfl_LICENSE
/usr/share/doc/php-mbstring-5.6.25/oniguruma_COPYING
/usr/share/doc/php-mbstring-5.6.25/ucgendat_LICENSE

[~]# rpm -qa 'php*'
php-pecl-zip-1.13.4-1.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64
php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.10-1.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64
php-mbstring-5.6.25-1.el6.remi.x86_64
php-common-5.6.25-1.el6.remi.x86_64
```

Comment: It would be useful to [edit] the question to include the output of `php -v` , `php -m | grep mbstring` and `php -i | grep mbstring`.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan : Updated with the results

Comment: Interesting. Did you configure a third-party repo to install PHP 5.6? I would also add the output of `rpm -qa 'php*'` to the question. It might also be worth checking the output `rpm -qil php-mbstring` for anything unusual.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan : I have updated the result. there are mbsting.so in
/usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/mbstring.so
/usr/lib64/php/modules/mbstring.so
But my extenstions path is: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226 
And also: I have upgraded PHP 5.3 to 5.6

Comment: Output of `rpm -qa 'php*'`?

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan : Updated with the result of rpm -qa 'php*'

Comment: I thought there may be a possibility of different versions of PHP installed on your system but that's not the case. The only other thing I can think of is checking the contents of `/etc/php.d/20-mbstring.ini` to ensure that it contains `extension=mbstring.so`.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan : Yes there is "extension=mbstring.so". But I couldn't find any other PHP version remain. Will that be problem as I mentioned, my extension path is "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226". But there is no mbstring.so.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan : :O `rpm -ql php` returns 'package php is not installed'

Comment: That extension directory doesn't sound right to me. [edit] the question to include the output of `php -i |grep ^extension_dir`. I think it should be `/usr/lib64/php/modules` (if not, you should find which php.ini file it has been changed in after verifying that the output of `ls /usr/lib64/php/modules` includes `mbstring.so`).

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan : Yes It looks like abnormal path. Anyway, thats the path showing as PHP `extension_dir` path even in the phpinfo(). And there is a mbstring.so in the `/usr/lib64/php/modules`.  I changed the module path, restarted. Then gave PDO not found from my PHP function. And still there is no mbstring in the phpinfo(). This looks like messed-up server config. I think its better to wiped-out existing PHP and reinstall as a fresh

Answer (score 2):

Installing PHP extensions/modules via RPM will install the library files into `/usr/lib64/php/modules/`.  Running `php -i |grep ^extension_dir` shows the extension directory that is currently configured.

An extension directory of `/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226` indicates that at some stage in the past, PHP was installed from source and that a `php.ini` file relating to this source installation is currently being used instead of the `/etc/php.ini` provided by the `php-common` package.

To solve this problem, you should remove the remnants of this source installation. Unfortunately, the Makefile provided with PHP source code doesn’t include an `uninstall` target so you can’t simply run `make uninstall`. I’d suggest using the `find` command to track down these files by their modification date.

Comment: I am highly appreciate your time & effort to this. However all of these configurations had done through EazyApache. (I got this to know after all of these tries) There are some unusual changes (rather doing directly on the server) because of installing/upgrades through EazyApache. So have to follow EazyApache to install new modules. Ref: https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/enable-install-mbstring-module.158165/

Comment: @Sadee That hurts! The fact that EazyApache was installed on the server was crucial information. Had you mentioned this vital fact in the  question, we wouldn't have had to put so much effort into debugging. Shouldn't I get some reputation in return for spending all that time on you question? Now I know why cPanel questions were banned from [sf]. :(